# Radix Ordering on Words

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Lothaire's Algebraic Combinatorics on Words gives the following definition of a total ordering, the radix order, on the set of finite words formed from an ordered alphabet $A$:

> The radix order is defined by $x\leq y$ if $|x|<|y|$ or $|x|=|y|$ and $x=uax'$ and $y=uby'$ with $a,b$ letters and $a\leq b$.

However, this definition doesn't make sense to me, particularly the second part, as we could have $a=b$ and then have some the letter following $b$ be less than $a$, which would mean that this definition would also gives us $y\leq x$. I feel like this is a mistake, and it was intended as:

> The radix order is defined by $x< y$ if $|x|<|y|$ or $|x|=|y|$ and $x=uax'$ and $y=uby'$ with $a,b$ letters and $a< b$.

However, the text's [errata page](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Lothaire/AlgCWErrata.pdf) gives no indication of this. Am I mistaken or misinterpreting the meaning here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation of what the radix order was supposed to be is correct; you can see this from the last sentence in the paragraph defining the lexicographic order. My guess is that he wanted to define the radix order as a non-strict partial order and was a little careless. Your definition gives the strict version of the radix order; for the non-strict version that he apparently wanted, you need an extra alternative.

> The radix order is defined by $x\le y$ if $|x|<|y|$, or $|x|=|y|$ and there are factorizations $x=uax'$ and $y=uby'$ with $a,b$ letters and $a<b$, or $x=y$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also, it turns out that I was wrong- there's another errata page that provides this correction. http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Lothaire/AppliedCW/ErrataAppliedCW.pdf

Comment: @Kevin: You’re welcome. (I wonder whether it really did take a while for that error to surface; I can certainly imagine that a lot of people simply read what was meant instead of what was written.)